# how to call startActivity in RecyclerView Adapter (DataBinding)

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

My `RecyclerView(rvPredictionIndex)` item includes `ImageView`, `EditText` and `Button`, when `Button` is clicked the Text inside `EditText` will be uploaded on server and when `ImageView` is clicked, the New `Activity` will be called and the position of that Item will be passed to new activity using `Intent()`.

I am using `DataBinding` so `View()` is not used here (or any other way of using `View()` than i don't know).

**Here is RecyclerView Adapter code....**

```
public class PredictionItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PredictionItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<PredictionItems> mPredictionItemsList;
    private Context mContext;
    private int predictionId;
    private String etAnswer;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //        ImageView ivPredictionImage;
//        CustomTextView txtPredictionQuestion;
        PredictionItemBinding predictionItemBinding;

        public MyViewHolder(PredictionItemBinding predictionItemBinding) {
            super(predictionItemBinding.getRoot());
            this.predictionItemBinding = predictionItemBinding;
//            ivPredictionImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPredictionImage);
//            txtPredictionQuestion = (CustomTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPredictionQuestion);
        }
    }

    public PredictionItemAdapter(Context context, List<PredictionItems> mPredictionItemsList) {
        this.mPredictionItemsList = mPredictionItemsList;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
//        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.prediction_item, parent, false);
//        return new MyViewHolder(view);
        PredictionItemBinding predictionItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.prediction_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(predictionItemBinding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
//        PredictionItems predictionItems = mPredictionItemsList.get(position);
//        Picasso.with(mContext).load(predictionItems.getImage()).into(holder.ivPredictionImage);
//        holder.txtPredictionQuestion.setText(predictionItems.getQuestion());
        final PredictionItems predictionItems = mPredictionItemsList.get(position);

        PredictionViewModel predictionViewModel = new PredictionViewModel(predictionItems);
        predictionViewModel.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
                if (propertyId == 1) {
                    etAnswer = holder.predictionItemBinding.editText.getText().toString();
                    predictionId = mPredictionItemsList.get(position).getId();
                    if (etAnswer.equals("")) {
                        Utility.showToastShort(mContext, "Please input answer");
                    } else {
                        callUpdatePredictionAnswerApi(predictionId, etAnswer);
//                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "submjit of " + holder.getAdapterPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else if (propertyId == 2){
                    //Here i want to start activity and pass data with intent
                }
            }
        });
        holder.predictionItemBinding.setPredictionVM(predictionViewModel);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPredictionItemsList.size();
    }
}
```

I have already opened new activity on ItemClick of recyclerView but when i tried to click the EditText for input something, it will redirect me to the new activity, so that's why i want to start new activity on ImageView click..

**here is my RecyclerViewItem Click...**

```
private void rvPredictionIndexClick() {
        rvPredictionIndex.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(mContext, rvPredictionIndex, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                String preId = mPredictionItemsList.get(position).getId().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, PredictionInfoActivity.class);
                String posi = ((String.valueOf(position)));
                i.putExtra("predictionId", posi);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: What is **rvPredictionIndex** ?

Comment: rvPrediction is a RecyclerView

Comment: rvPredictionIndexClick is outside the adapter if i am not wrong ? . just wanted to be sure before answering

Comment: addOnItemTouchListener is basically calls everytime you touch the recyclerview item. Rather than that you have to do individual onItemClickListeners for ImageView?

Comment: do you want open activity when rvPredictionIndexClick called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Class `DataBindingAdapter` 
and paste

```
  @BindingAdapter("android:onClick")
    public static void setOnClickListener(View view, final Runnable runnable) {
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                runnable.run();
            }
        });
    }
```

than go to your `ViewModel` class
and paste

```
   public void onSubmitClicked() {
        Log.e("onButtonSubmit", "onButtonSubmit");
        notifyPropertyChanged(1);
    }

    public void onImageClicked() {
        Log.e("onImageClicked", "onImageClicked");
        notifyPropertyChanged(2);
    }
```

than go to your `item.xml` file and call

```
android:onClick="@{predictionVM::onSubmitClicked}"
```

in your Button,
and

```
android:onClick="@{predictionVM.onImageClicked}
```

in your imaggView,
than go to your `ItemAdapterClass` 
and inside `onCreateViewHolder`

```
  predictionViewModel.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
                if (propertyId == 1) {
                 //do your stuff
               }
               else if (propertyId == 2) {
                   // do your stuff

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant and frankly adequate solution would be not to do anything inside adapter! 
I wrote an article about adapters, have a look [RecyclerView Adapters](https://medium.com/androidsolutions/recyclerview-adapters-4d39a24da3c0)

Straightforward: add a callback to your adapter and perform everything inside calling sight (fragment etc)

Comment: @toNysTark what do you mean by that?

Comment: okk got it, the article is helpful and gave me 2 more ideas for improving my code. thx @GeorgySavatkov